# Sound not working Focal Fossa Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: audio, bluetooth, kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using ubuntu 20.04 recently and have a HP pavillion laptop with B&O speakers. However i am not able to hear any sound. though, Bluetooth is working fine.

I have tried many solutions such as :

*`sudo apt purge timidity-daemon`

*`sudo alsa force-reload`

*`sudo apt install pavucontrol` and running `pavucontrol`.

**None** of the solutions have worked for me yet.

EDIT:
Later I assumed it to be a kernel bug and say a solution using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kaihengfeng/fix-lp1869819
sudo apt-get update
```

after that i have tried reinstalling pulseaudio. And now bluetooth devices just after getting connected are automatically disconnected, do not play any sound either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, after surfing a lot through the net and reading about options of alsa for NVIDIA aound controller I got the following solution

2 files are to be changed

1. `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

### Changes in File 1.

- open the file using root
- add the following line to the bottom of the file `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
- save and exit the file

### Changes in File 2.

- open the file using root
- add the following to the bottom of the line `blacklist snd_soc_skl`
- save and exit the file.

Reboot and Enjoy with the restored sound!

Comment: This worked well with me. Would appreciate for explaining, what exactly these two changes are making.

Comment: It appears that the instructions for file 1 and file 2 are reversed.

Comment: With a new issue - I had to return to this topic: this solution is ommiting detection of built in mic and blacklisting it from availiavle devices. As a result - your setup will work only with external mic (which was not a problem to me for a while). Problem for me started, when I tried switch to new headphones with no built in mic.

Answer (score 11):

The Temporary fix I found(Worked for me and all my friends).

Suspend your system then start again. Now the sound will work.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well.

Comment: Wow I thought it wouldn't work, thanks :D

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me immediately after all was

```
pulseaudio --start
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

from https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/

with no changes to the files in /etc/modprobe.d/

Answer (score 4):

This is silly but After days of searching, upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 then installing fresh 20.04 it still not solved,
which finally got solved by just

```
go to BIOS -> disable Internal Speakers -> apply changes -> Enable again -> Apply changes -> Exit.
```

Voila Problem is solved :) :) (Dell Latitude 3510)

Comment: Dell Latitude 3510 here: tried this option, but it worked only until first interaction with audio streams (for me it was starting of Spotify). So - not an ption.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues. I would get no audio output, except for when I plugged an HDMI in which case I could redirect the sound to the HDMI device. I've tried all the previous answer and it didn't work for my case I have a **Dell inspiron 9510** and had  **ubuntu 20.04** freshly installed.

I made all the different changes in the files

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

this never worked for me. I've tried a lot of things, disable internal speakers in BIOS and such, still nothing. I've spent hours trying to fix this.
Finally I found this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1895422
and this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/husu3r/how_to_get_fully_working_audio_in_ubuntu_2004_on/

Basically what you got to do is to allow focal-proposed updates first:

Software & Updates > "Developer options" tab > check "pre-released updates" box.

From here you can already do a

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Then you can install the linux-oem-20.04

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04
```

This will install a new kernel (5.6.0-1036-oem) where sound as proper support apparently. Now just reboot you system and you should be good to go.

You can find more info on this on the links provided. Also the second link has additional steps but for me only the first one worked like a charm !

I hope this can help anyone here who is running into the same issue. If anyone has found another way I'd be also glad to hear it since using a linux-oem is not a completely satisfying method.

Comment: After all troubleshooting trying different thing, This was the only solution that worked for me. I'm on Dell Inspiron 15

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!, following RolandBBerlin at:
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2055691
I just installed an Acer Swift 3 (SF314-57) and encountered the same problem. This solved the Audio problems:

```
**Edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** and add the following lines:

**options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic enable=yes**

The first line is to enable the speaker, the second for the internal microphone.
```

Works after rebooting

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't have any output and input devices on sound settings
just type on terminal the following command `pulseaudio --start` and try to turn on video or audio, but when you reboot your system you need to retype the command.
In my case it was the temporary solution.